# only one radio buttons

Tags: java, android

I have read in an example that if you use more than one radio button you should use `RadioGroup` like this:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
           android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
           android:text="@string/attendance"
           android:textSize="8dp"

            />
   <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/radio_pirates2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
           android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
           android:text="@string/attendance"
           android:textSize="8dp"

            />
       </RadioGroup>
```

If I have only one radio button, can I remove `<RadioGroup>` or that is wrong ?

Comment: If you only want one radiobutten, you actually want a checkbox

Comment: because i have 2 functions if check do this and if not do this

Comment: @Minion91 i can not use radio ? because checkbox is not good idea with my program

Comment: Radio buttons are designed to be a group of "mutually exclusive buttons". The idea is that you have a group of buttons and when you push one in, the others pop out If you only have one button then radio button is definitely the wrong UI component to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html)

> A radio button is a two-states button that can be either checked or
>   unchecked. When the radio button is unchecked, the user can press or
>   click it to check it. However, contrary to a CheckBox, a radio button
>   cannot be unchecked by the user once checked.

**However, contrary to a CheckBox, a radio button
 cannot be unchecked by the user once checked.**

So, if you wish to give only one option button to select the user then use `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton`